# How to recursively search all parentNodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to know, how to find out recursively all parent nodes of an element.
Suppose i have following snippet

`<a href="#"><font>Hello</font></a>`

In this I would like to find out whether font tag's parent node is an anchor tag or not.
Now this can be achieved by simply checking .parentNode property. But what if there are following cases like,

`<a href="#"><font><b>Hello<b></font></a>`

or

`<a href="#"><font><b><u>Hello</u><b></font></a>`

So, basically, how to know if we have reached the top most parent node ?

Comment: font tag's immediate  parent node is an anchor tag .. in all the scenarios, plz modify your question

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can traverse from an element up to the root looking for the desired tag:

```
function findUpTag(el, tag) {
    while (el.parentNode) {
        el = el.parentNode;
        if (el.tagName === tag)
            return el;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You call this method with your start element:

```
var el = document.getElementById("...");  // start element
var a = findUpTag(el, "A");   // search <a ...>
if (a) console.log(a.id);
```

Comment: Bingo. Recurse, recurse, recurse.

Comment: There's no recursion here! Just an iterative loop.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work with event.target? All I'm doing is adding event.target when calling findUpTag: `findUpTag(event.target, 'B'`, simply returns blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Nice! I started writing up some recursion but a while loop is probably faster.

Comment: Response : you can use `closest()` function from your HTML Element
Docs here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Note: this only works when specifying uppercase `tag`.

Answer (score 1):

The following recursive function will return an **ascending ordered array**, with all the parents nodes for the provided DOM element, **until BODY node is reached**.

```
function parents(element, _array) {
    if(_array === undefined) _array = []; // initial call
    else _array.push(element); // add current element
    // do recursion until BODY is reached
    if(element.tagName !== 'BODY' ) return parents(element.parentNode, _array);
    else return _array;
}
```

Usage :

```
var parentsArray = parents( document.getElementById("myDiv") );
```

Comment: Recursion = slow, terrible performance. Just about no exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Since 2015 or so, one can just use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
const startElement = document.getElementBy...
if (startElement.closest("a") != null) { 
    // Has <a> tag ancestor.
}
```

(I realize this is an old question, but it still comes up on top in Google (eg. "javascript find parent element recursive") and I was surprised not to see a more modern answer here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery closest() method to get the closest ahref:

```
$("#your-element").closest("a").css("color", "red");
```

Or you can have a look at the [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) method:

```
$("#your-element").parentsUntil("#yourWrapper", "a").first().css("color", "red");
```

Try it out here: http://www.lunarailways.com/demos/parents.html

Comment: A vanilla JS solution would have been more informative than jQuery, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I been working on similar thing. Trying to close a div if user clicks outside the div. It needs to loop through all its parent nodes.

have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/y7mEY/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter one:

```js
function parentByTag(el, tag) {
    if(!el || el.tagName == tag) {
        return el
    } else {
        return parentByTag(el.parentElement, tag)
    }
}
```

Returns `undefined` if not found.