# How to change the color of a table row from javascript after closing a pop up which is opened using a button in the table row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have requirement to change the color of a table row as below

A table is having multiple lines, each having a button/image. When the user clicks on this button/image on a particular line, a pop up is opened. After saving the data successfully, the row from which the pop up is opened has to change its color. Here table, rows and cells are already having id's and style classes.

For this I used various ways as below

**1.**

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('rowId'+lineNumber).style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";
```

**2.**

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('rowId'+lineNumber).className="innerrowcss";
```

**3.**

```
 var tbl = window.opener.document.getElementById('linesTableId');
 tbl.rows[lineNumber].style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";
```

**or**

```
tbl.rows[lineNumber].style.className="innerrowcss";
```

None of the above options helped me changing the color of the required row.

Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks,
Eshwari

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7333885/3863146) answer. The function **findUpTag(el, 'tr')**, gives the row for which you want to change the color. Then change the color of the row: `row.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";`.

Answer (score 0):

is `rowID + lineNumber` the `tr`? this does´nt work. Search the `<td>` inside.

```js
var id = 2;
var el = document.querySelectorAll('table .rowId' + id + ' td');
// go trough all <td>´s and add the color
for( var i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; i++) {
  el[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="rowId1">
     <td>row 1</td><td>row 1.1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="rowId2">
     <td>row 2</td><td>row 2.1</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```