# Clone Node true only one level

Tags: javascript, dom, clonenode

I want to clone a Node with only level 1 of children, so no children of children.

```
<div data-a>
 <div> data-a1>
  <div data-a11>
   <p> fdsafdsafds</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If I have the last level as target

`target.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true)` will clone all levels, I want data-a to be cloned including data-a1 but data-a1 no have no children.

It is possible to remove/add children cloned or not, bases on depth level or their attributes(clone the parent with only children that have or not a specified attribute) ?

I thing based on attributes if I will have something with more depth levels, instead just parentNode.parentNode using recursion.

Comment: I'd suggest a full clone and subsequently removing all nodes you are no interested in. Afaik there is no way to clone only a subset on the first place.

Comment: Or the other way around, a shallow clone first, and then you loop over the children of the original element and “import” them by cloning and appending them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to remove the `innerHTML` of the first `children`

```
var dupeNode = target.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
dupeNode.children[0].innerHTML = "";
```

**Demo**

```js
var target = document.querySelector( "p" );
var dupeNode = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
dupeNode.children[0].innerHTML = "";
//console.log(dupeNode.outerHTML);
document.querySelector( "#container" ).appendChild( dupeNode );
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div data-a=""> data-a level text to be cloned
    <div data-a1="">
      <div data-a11="">
        <p> fdsafdsafds</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, can you give me an example using recursion (having more dept levels) instead of just two.

Comment: @user3541631 I have attached a demo, you can check this solution for how to check parentNodes based on recursion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332179/how-to-recursively-search-all-parentnodes